# Request via dynamic finders in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've three domain classess:

```
class Cafee {

    String cafeeName

    static hasMany = [halls: HallsZones]

    static constraints = {
        halls nullable: true
    }
}

class HallsZones {
    String hallName

    static scaffold = true
    static hasMany = [table : TablePlacesInfo]
    static belongsTo = [cafee : Cafee]

    static constraints = {
        table nullable: true
        cafee nullable: true
    }
}

class TablePlacesInfo {
    int placesInTableAmount
    int tableAmount
    int tableForReservationAmount
    int placeCost
    String currencyType

    static scaffold = true
    static belongsTo = [hall: HallsZones]

    static constraints = {
        hall nullable: true
    }
}
```

As you can see, classess are connected with each other as via chain:

```
Cafee-(hasMany)->HallsZones-(hasMany)->TablePlacesInfo.
```

I want to get TablePlaces info, which has HallsZones as parent which in turn has a Cafee as parent.
I know how to search by parent, for example:

```
def table = TablePlacesInfo.findWhere(hall : params['hallsAvailable'], placesInTableAmount : Integer.parseInt(params['tablePlacesAvailable']))
```

But how to search by grandparent too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `where` query:

```
TablePlacesInfo.where {
    hall {
        cafee {
            // criteria matching grand parent
            id == 1L // for example
        }
    }
}.list()
```

Using `Criteria`:

```
TablePlacesInfo.withCriteria {
    hall {
        cafee {
            // criteria matching grand parent
            idEq 1L // for example
        }
    }
}
```

Using `hql`:

```
TablePlacesInfo.executeQuery(
    """select tpi from TablePlacesInfo as tpi 
       inner join tpi.hall as hall 
       inner join hall.cafee as caf 
       where caf.id = 1"""
)
```

Choosing a `DetachedCriteria` or `where` would be a sound approach instead of dynamic finders.

Comment: `id` in domain classes are Long by default, hence 1L (Long 1) for comparison, although in case of where query it would be coerced as long, but I was being specific.